# Elle a de/des longs cheveux

Tags: grammaire, articles, pluriel, déterminants

Considérant les deux phrases suivantes

1. Elle a des cheveux noirs
2. Elle a **de** longs cheveux noirs

Quelle est la règle qui explique l'utilisation de "de" au lieu de "des" dans la deuxième phrase ?

Comment: Elle aurait plutôt **les** cheveux noirs, pour moi. Enfin, elle s'accroche peut-être au peu qu'il lui reste de jeunesse, m'enfin…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Il s'agit dans les deux cas d'un [article indéfini](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_ind%C3%A9fini). La forme normale de l'article est *des*, mais il y a [deux cas où on utilise *de*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_ind%C3%A9fini#Remarques_sur_l.27article_ind.C3.A9fini_pluriel).

- Systématiquement, lorsque l'existence des objets est niée (et que cette négation est exprimée grammaticalement dans la phrase).

  > Elle n'a pas **de** cheveux gris.
- Souvent, lorsqu'il y a un adjectif entre le déterminant et le nom (que ce soit un épithète ou un second déterminant).

  > Elle a **de** longs cheveux.
  >   Je cherche **d'**autres exemples.

Il y a des exceptions dans ce deuxième cas. Dans un certain nombre d'expressions, on considère que l'adjectif et le nom forment un tout, et on utilise *des* : **des** petits pois, **des** grands frères¹. On utilise plus souvent *des* à l'oral ; la langue est probablement en train d'évoluer dans le sens de l'abandon du *de* ici. Il y a un certain nombre de cas ambigus pour lesquels on trouve des citations littéraires utilisant *de* ou *des* ; voir par exemple Grevisse ([article reproduit ici](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29309&p=54802&hilit=%C3%A9pith%C3%A8te+remplac%C3%A9#p54802)).

¹  <sub>Des grands frères = des frères plus âgés (*older brothers*) ; de grands frères = des frères qui sont grands (*tall brothers*).</sub>

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour la réponse complète

Comment: D'où vient cette préférence du "de" à "des" quand il y a un déterminant antéposé?

Comment: @rds Ça, je ne sais pas. Je pourrais pipeauter l'euphonie, mais ça reste vaseux. Ni ce qui fait que dans certaines phrases *de* ou *des* sonne mal et dans d'autres les deux sont possibles (*de* étant plutôt plus relevé dans ce cas).

Comment: De façon générale, le "de" est plus soutenu. Généralement, le "des" reste possible, mais parfois "des" sonne vraiment mal. Tu indiques les exceptions où seul "des" est possible (je ne pense pas qu'il y en ait d'autres, si?)

Comment: Sans aller si loin, j'aurais simplement dit "elle a des cheveux noirs" ça veut dire que ce n'est pas sa couleur prédominante mais que dans le tas ya des cheveux noirs. "Elle a les cheveux noirs" c'est de façon général. Pareil pour la phrase du dessous