# Usage of "de" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: pluriel, articles

I came across the following translation and I was unsure why the sentence started with "de"

> Little girls read books.

Translation:

> De petites filles lisent des livres.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this sentence, *de* is the plural form of the [indefinite article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_article#Indefinite_article). It means that some little girls read books.

Usually the plural indefinite article is *des*. However it becomes *de* in two cases:

- When the noun group is a direct object of a verb in a negative sentence.

  > Le chat mange des souris.
  >   Le chat ne mange pas de souris.  [direct object → *de*]
  >
  > Les chats sont des souris.
  >   Les chats ne sont pas des souris. [*[attribut du sujet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribut_du_sujet)*, i.e. complement to a [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) → *des*]
- Sometimes when there is an adjective before the noun. The article is always *des* when the adjective and the noun form a set phrase, but it is *de* in careful speech otherwise. I don't think *des* is ever incorrect in this case.

  > des beaux yeux *or* de beaux yeux
  >   des petites filles *or* de petites filles
  >
  > de petit pains *(small loaves of bread)*
  >   des petits pains *(specific bread shapes, with regional variations; in some regions, a kind of chocolate croissant)*
  >
  > de petits enfants *(small children)*
  >   des petits-enfants *(grandchildren)*

The English sentence could also mean that little girls in general (i.e. all or at least many little girls) read books. This meaning would call for a definite article: “*Les petites filles lisent des livres*”.

Comment: Don't you consider this question a duplicate of this one http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/elle-a-de-des-longs-cheveux ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I hadn't noticed this question. It would have saved me time writing this answer! But it isn't a complete duplicate: here the primary question is knowing what *de* means; the bulk of my answer explains why it is used instead of *des* but it's additional background information.

Comment: Since you wrote the other answer, I thought you'd remember it :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=8725274#8725274