# Quand utiliser « les », « des », « l' » ou « d' » avant des mots qui commencent par une voyelle ou un « h » ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, élision

Je sais pas quand, avant des mots qui sont pluriels, je dois utiliser *les*, *des*, *l'* ou *d'* lorsque le mot commence par une voyelle ou un *h*.

Par exemple, quelle est la différence entre:

- L'enfant
- Les enfants
- D'enfant
- Des enfants

?

Je veux savoir quelles formes sont correctes et lesquelles sont typiquement utilisées.

(Merci d'avance. I will appreciate an answer in **English**.)

Answer (score 3):

There are three separate issues.

*L'* is always short for *le* and *d'* is always short for *de*. *Les* and *des* are never elided. The same goes for *je*, *me*, *ne*, *se*, *te*.

The elided form (*d'*, *l'*, …) is used when the next word starts with a vowel sound: *le fils*, *l'enfant*. Semi-vowels count as vowels: *l'iode*, *l'oiseau*. The letter H is special: although it is never actually pronounced, it counts as a consonant in some words ([aspirated H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_h)), while it doesn't count in other words (silent H). The general rule is that words derived from Latin or Greek roots have a slient H while words built on Germanic and other roots have an aspirated H (there are exceptions).

This covers the easy part. The third and more difficult issue is that there are multiple words spelled *de*.

- A preposition: “*le livre de ma sœur*” (lit. “the book of my sister”, i.e. my sister's book); “*il sort de la maison*” (“he comes out of the house”).
  **<s>De le</s>* is contracted to *du* and **<s>De les</s>* is contracted to *des*.
- The first part of the [partitive article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive_article#Partitive_article): “il boit de la bière” (“he drinks (some) beer”). Here *de la* is the partitive article; the fact that it looks like *de* followed by the definite article is a coincidence.
  Again, **<s>de le</s>* is contracted to *du* and **<s>De les</s>* is contracted to *des*.
- The plural indefinite article; this is normally *des* but sometimes *de*.

Especially on that last topic, see also [Usage of "de" at the beginning of a sentence](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8182/usage-of-de-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence) and [When to use du instead of des?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/when-to-use-du-instead-of-des)

Comment: _"The same goes for je, me, ne, se, te."_ je is often elided in j', ne is often elided in n', se in s'… me may be elided in m' if it's part of a dialog (because it is elided orally) : « Je m’suis fait avoir »

Answer (score 2):

*Les* and *Des* are never shortened to *L'* and *D'*.

*Le* and *De* are shortened when located before a vowel or a mute h. There is also *la* (la amie -> l'amie), *que* (que il vienne -> qu'il vienne) and others like *te*, *me* and similar.

Comment: “La” is shortened too :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Sure, and several others. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm bad at grammar.

> L'enfant  = The kid
>
> Un enfant = A kid
>
> Les enfants = The kids
>
> Des enfants = Some kids

I guess you know the difference beetween "the" and "a" in english, it's the same in french.
In your example, "D'enfant" is the contraction of "de":

> Les jeux d'enfants  = The games of kids
>
> Je viens d'afrique = I come from Africa
>
> Je viens des montagnes = I come from mountains

If you have "le arbre" it will be "l'arbre" the same way than "a apple" -> "an apple" for easiest pronunciation

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. In fact, my question is only about plural nouns. Really often, the French use l'something instead of les something. It is the same with d/des. Is it correct?

Comment: I think we don't do that. Les and des are never shortened

Answer (score 0):

I think that this page has a very clear explanation. It is all in French, though:

http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3227.php

Here is the part about why it may seem like des is sometimes changed to de/de la/du in English:

"Des" in the negative construction or in front of a qualitative plural adjective placed before the noun becomes "de" or "d'" (in front of a vowel):

• Elle a des robes. ==> Elle *n’a pas* **de** robes / Elle a **de** *belles* robes.

• J’ai vu des animaux. ==> Je *n’ai pas* vu **d’** animaux / J’ai vu **d'** *énormes* animaux.