# De petites chambres vs. des petites chambres

Tags: articles, pluriel

What is the correct phrase: *de petites chambres* or *de**s** petites chambres*? I believe that *de petites chambres* is the corrected version, but why?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/elle-a-de-des-longs-cheveux

Answer (score 7):

Il y a une différence de sens :

> *Cet hôtel a de petites chambres* signifie que toutes les chambres de l'hôtel sont petites (par rapport à la moyenne, ou par rapport à ce que l'on attend, etc.).
>
> *Cet hôtel a des petites chambres* laisse entendre qu'il possède aussi des chambres plus grandes.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, it depends on what you want to say (and usage, too, to some extent). Using `de` here is an undefinite article, contraction of `de des`: you are talking about small rooms in general. Using `des` here is a definite article, contraction of `de les`: you are talking about some specific, identified small rooms.

Examples of padbrest in the other answer are great illustrations of that difference.

Comment: Un commentaire sur le pourquoi du vote négatif ne fait jamais de mal? :/

Comment: No idea, great answer!

Comment: What you wrote is simply wrong in this context. *Des* is the contraction *de les* only when *de* is a preposition. There is no preposition in this sentence.