# Why is "de" used instead of "des" in this statement that begins with "Il y a..."

Tags: grammaire, articles

I was reading my French textbook and I encountered a sentence that I have trouble understanding it. The sentence is: "Il y a de nombreuses organisations internationales." Why is "de" used in this case instead of "des" when it is followed by plural noun?

Comment: Look at http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/elle-a-de-des-longs-cheveux  et aussi http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13622/de-petites-chambres-vs-des-petites-chambres/13625#13625

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quand l'adjectif vient avant le nom, on utilise « de » au lieu de « des » . Par exemple :

- "Il y a des voitures dans ce parking."
- "Il y a des voitures rouges dans ce parking."

mais

- "Il y a **de** vielles voitures dans ce parking."

Moi, je n'ai aucune idée pourquoi c'est ainsi, mais c'est la vie !

Comment: Point intéressant, si quelqu'un a une source... ? :)