# « De » ou « des » dans le cas des + adjectif + nom, quand « des » est une préposition

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

Je sais que dans le cas *des + adjectif + nom* l'article « des » est remplacé par « de », par exemple :

> Ce sont de belles fleurs.

Fait-on de même dans le cas où « des » renvoie à une préposition ? Par exemple, écrit-on « parler des grandes choses » ou « parler de grandes choses » ?

Je n'ai pas trouvé une seule explication dans ma grammaire ou sur le net. Pourtant, « parler de grandes choses » donne 126.000 résultats sur Google contre 70.000 pour « parler des grandes choses ».

---

J'essaie de clarifier que je me réfère au cas "préposition de + les + adjectif + nom" en présentant un exemple plus long :

> Nous avons fixé les nouveaux accords. Ainsi, nous espérons profiter des nouveaux accords.

OU

> Nous avons fixé les nouveaux accords. Ainsi, nous espérons profiter de nouveaux accords.

Quelle serait la variante correcte?

Comment: Ta règle n'est pas correcte : "J'ai des grandes oreilles" et "J'ai de grandes oreilles" sont sauf erreur 2 phrases valables. Je pense que tu en apprendras plus sur l'usage de "de" ou "des" dans les réponses à [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/elle-a-de-des-longs-cheveux)

Comment: L'ambiguïté de petit mot "de", et le fait que "ma règle" connaît en effet des exceptions, peut-être ont rendu peu claire ma question. Merci pour les réponses et les liens donnés.

J'essaie de clarifier que je me réfère au cas "préposition de + les + adjéctif + nom" en présentant un exemple plus long:

Nous avons fixé les nouveaux accords.

Ainsi, nous éspérons de profiter des nouveaux accords.
**OU**
Ainsi, nous éspérons de profiter de nouveaux accords.

Quelle serait l'alternative correcte?

Comment: Je remarque que quand l'usage de `de/des` est ambigu, c'est après un verbe qui s'emploie toujours avec **de**. On profite toujours **de** quelque chose, on vient **de** quelque part, on parle **de** certaines choses... Dans ces cas, je préfère le **de** au **des**, mais j'ignore s'il y a une règle.

Answer (score 0):

Si *grandes choses* représente :

- des objets, des entités dénombrables, on peut employer « parler des grandes choses, des grandes idées de la philosophie grecque, des grandes réalisations de la civilisation ».
- une idée, une entité singulière, on peut alors employer  « parler de grandes choses, de grandes idées philosophiques (qui concernent toutes les sphères de la philosophie), de grandes réalisations faites par les civilisations ».

> Ce sont *des* belles fleurs que voilà (on désigne un lot de fleur, ou un parterre particulier)
>
> Oh, comme ce sont *de* belles fleurs ! (toutes celles que mon regard peut embrasser)

Dans le doute, à l'écrit il est préférable de se cantonner au *de* qui semble plus soutenu ; l'oral utilise *des* plus facilement.

---

Parmi *[ces exemples](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29309&p=54802&hilit=%C3%A9pith%C3%A8te%20remplac%C3%A9#p54802)* certains pourraient avoir *des* au lieu de *de* et inversement, souvent parce que leur contexte n'est pas complet ou qu'une phrase sortie de son environnement ne peut servir de modèle systématique : il peut y avoir une intention de l'auteur de choisir *de* ou *des* dans la phrase écrite.

Answer (score 0):

*de* semble pouvoir être utilisé dans le cas des compléments prépositionnels aussi, comme si il était la fusion de la préposition et d'un déterminant indéfini pluriel :

- Paul arrive de quartiers plutôt originaux
- Marie a pourvu sa voiture de nouveaux enjoliveurs

Avec, probablement, un effet de concurrence avec *des* comme pour le déterminant.

---

Pour les nouveaux accords, s'il s'agit de profiter de ces nouveaux accords, la première variante est la bonne.
La deuxième ne fait pas de rapprochements entre les nouveaux accords de la premières phrases et ceux de la seconde.

Answer (score 0):

Dans ton premier exemple, "des" est la contraction de "de les". Ils sont nouveaux pour vous. Dans le deuxième exemple, le contexte dit que vous espérez avoir de nouveaux accords.

C'est comme ça que je l'interprète, les deux phrases veulent dire 2 choses différentes.